# Stereomix is not capturing the audio on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, audio, audio-recording

I have stereomix enabled in Windows 10 with its "Via HD Audio" driver, and it's not working as it was on Windows 7 with Realtek (I've also installed the driver for Realtek, and it made no difference).

[image]

I play an audio, and there's no sound going through stereomix. How can I fix it?